# Is there a way to export/import the individual syntax coloring from Eclipse to CLion?

Tags: eclipse, import, export, clion, color-scheme

I don't mean the color schemes, but the individual syntax coloring, that can be done in Eclipse under: Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring

What I've allready tried in Eclipse is: File -> Export -> General -> Preferences -> selection of "C/C++ Editor Appearance" and choosing [filename].xml or [filename].jar as file name.

Then in CLion: File -> Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> C/C++ -> clicking on the small gearwheel at the top -> Import Scheme -> selecting the jar-file (xml isn't selectable).

CLion then shows the error message, that it's not a valid scheme.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you can reproduce the Eclipse colors with enough configuration work of your own. Not sure why that would be so important, but clearly YMMV.

Did you find this site? https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes

If I go there and search for C++, one of the top results is "Classic Eclipse". There may be other Eclipse variations.

I haven't tried it myself but the site claims to let you download files for importing into CLion and other IntelliJ IDEs.

Comment: I don't want schemes other people have created, but my own, that I have created in Eclipse, so that I can work with the same coloring in CLion, because I'm used to it. But thank you for your answer, though.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Probably the most efficient solution for you is to find a CLion theme that is close to your own and tweak it to be closer. Or, you could treat the theme-difference as something of an exercise in making the adjustment of working with a new team. If you work as a professional programmer or even as the designated programmer within a science lab or business office, more often than not, there will be coding guidelines in place or existing code/tools you need to be compatible with. A bit of flexibility on the small things (like colors) can ease transitions and earn trust.